# I installed lubuntu on a different partition but on the same drive as windows 7 and no boot menu

Tags: boot, grub2, 13.04, lubuntu

After I installed Lubuntu, computer boots directly to windows 7 and its not showing the boot menu. 
Now I have access to windows only. 
During the installation I choose to install it on different partition and the boot file location I set it to the same partition I installed Lubuntu on and its not the partition that windows is installed in. 
windows on partition ==> sda1 and windows boot loader as well is here.
lubuntu and its boot loader ==> sda7.

what shall I do now ?
re-install lubuntu?

Comment: can you add the output of `sudo fdisk -l`.  Boot from the Lubuntu CD, and then get that output.

Comment: I can not boot into lubuntu 
it goes directly to windows as if lubuntu was not there

Comment: I am unable to take screen shot of it
the boot device is set to sda1

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

You need to Re-install grub to the MBR booting from the liveCD `/dev/sdaX`, where X is the root partition.

```
sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sdXX
sudo umount /mnt
```

And then reboot the machine, grub menu should come up now.

Note: windows 7 loader is listed in grub.cfg so re-installing grub will also give access to windows.

Based on your last comment, I would try to get a backup of all important files, just in case, and then re-install Lubuntu.

<sup>Source: Grub 2 Basics</sup>

Comment: when I entered the grub install command it said this : 
Path `/mnt/boot/grub' is not readable by GRUB on boot. Installation is impossible. Aborting.

Comment: when I reinstall it 
where should I specify the boot file location ??

Comment: I previously specified it to sda7 
shall I just leave it sda

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install Grub Bootloader to the entire disk to be able to select which operating system you want to use at boot, not just to the Lubuntu partition. You can follow [these instructions](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd#.UbMSelRDsZU) to do that with a Ubuntu or Lubuntu Live CD or USB.

Comment: mount: mount point /mnt/dev does not exist
 I get this when I try the 2nd command

Comment: the first command did not work either so I had to mount them myself using "Disks" application

Answer (score 0):

I re-installed the whole thing .. and did not mess with the boot loader location option and everything is working fine.

Thanks guys in advance.